# NextJS Application error: a client-side exception has occurred

Tags: heroku, next.js, next.js13

I have the following problem in a NextJS app on Heroku.
(Next: 14.0.1)

This is a link pointing to a dynamic route:

```
https://myapp.herokuapp.com/LYS5569npeck
```

I can open it in my Firefox browser and see what I expect.

On the other hand, I have this kind of code in a component:

```
return <div>
    {
        theResult.map(item => (
            <div key={item as string}>
              <Link href={item}>{item}</Link>
          </div>
      ))
    }
```

To make things short, this component is just listing the different dynamic routes like the one mentioned earlier. When it is displayed in the browser, I can use the mouse right click and choose "Copy Link" to confirm that the link above appears in the list as expected.

Therefore by checking the proper item in the list I can get back the same link:

```
https://myapp.herokuapp.com/LYS5569npeck
```

But when I click this item is when things go wrong. Instead of getting the same thing as I first got. I now see this in the browser:

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
```

It seems like other people have also hit similar issues, but I don't see any solution that I can apply.

Is it possible that I did something wrong writing the NextJS app ?

It may be useful to note that I have tried the app with three different browsers and getting the same behavior: Firefox, Safari and Brave.

In Firefox this is what I get as an error when I look at the browser console for more information :

```
TypeError: s().connect is not a function
    NextJS 10
        connectMDB
        audioChunks
        AudioList
        Mf
        rC
        Jk
        Mk
        tk
        qf
        P
```

By experimenting slightly differently (changing the code to build a link a different way), I get this error:

```
AbortError: Actor 'Conduits' destroyed before query 'RuntimeMessage' was resolved 2 ConduitsParent.sys.mjs:362
    _raceResponses resource://gre/modules/ConduitsParent.sys.mjs:362
```

Comment: Have you taken the advice that the error has given you? It clearly states: `see the browser console for more information`, and if so; What exactly does the error say?

Comment: Yes of course but I could not make use of it to solve the problem. In fact I just added this piece of information at the end of my post. You can have a look.